# yii2 modal attribute as required dynamically

Tags: yii2, yii2-model, yii2-validation

I have a case where a field is mandatory, but not always mandatory. If I write the attribute as required in modal `rules()` like: `[['my_attribute'], 'required']` then it would make the field required in every case. 
can I make a specific modal's attribute as required? in controller's or modal's custom function (i.e the place where I need the field to be mandatory).

P.S: i want to avoid jQuery and JavaScript. Please answer if there is a way in Yii2 to get it done :) thanks.

Comment: show what you had tried? Unclear what you are asking.

Comment: i have already written my approach above - the rule() required one and the one via jQuery. Do you know any proper way of doing it by yii2 standards?

Comment: you can use scenario.

Comment: well its done :) i have overridden the rules() function. Actually i didn't want to do it using scenarios because the work flow in both of my cases are same except 1 attribute. So i was avoiding redundancy. Anyways thanks :)

can you please guide me how to close the question? i am new to this.

Comment: may be you can delete or definitely vote for close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `when` from [here](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-validator.html)
So, it will be look like that:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['password', 'required', 'when' => function($model) {
            return $model->role === 'user'; // boolean should be returned
        }]
    ];
}
```

It will check the attribute on `required` condition only when `$model` s role is `user`